# Visual Studio - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

¿Alguien sabe por qué no puedo cambiar la opción de proveedor heredado?

Requiero ponerla en true, como el proyecto de la derecha y me aparece bloqueado.

De antemano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de casualidad el VS esta ejecutando la aplicacion? cuando intentas cambiar esta opcion

Comment: @LeandroTuttini No amigo, no se esta ejecutando

Comment: te estas conectando al mismo tipo de base de datos?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Si, es el mismo motor, diferente instancia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empieza con un modelo vacío y debería haber una propiedad llamada "Estrategia de generación de código" o algo así (no estoy seguro yo tengo VS en inglés).

[image: Propiedades]

Cambia la propiedad a la otra opción, la que no sea "T4".  La propiedad "Usar proveedor heredado" (*Use Legacy Provider*) debería cambiar a `True`

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono a la perfección!